# Jobs that I already applied for should be removed from the list or at least marked

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

I applied for a job that is still showing on the Jobs ad list, which is really annoying and confusing at the same time. What I suggest is one of the following:

- if a user applied for a job it should not appear anymore as a job ad
- if a user applied for a job it will be shown in ad list but it will marked in a way it will be differentiate from other jobs

[image]

Comment: Protip: asking for upvotes is a good way to get downvotes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't envision a circumstance where an advertisement would be able to retrieve account state to give you a slightly better experience when looking/clicking on it.

At a minimum I would say that the ad should take you to the application page and *there* indicate that you've applied for it already.  If the ad had more information than it absolutely needed to present jobs to you, then that could be seen as problematic from a personal security perspective; if I had these ads enabled, I'd question why it knows what things I've applied to given that I'm not on the Jobs site.